# i cant connect springboot and sqlite

Tags: java, spring, sqlite, jpa, dialect

I can't connect SQLite database with spring boot. I read a lot about it and learned that a dialect should be written for SQLite. I write the dialect, but when I write registerColumnType, it gives me an error: Cannot resolve method 'registerColumnType' in 'SQLiteDialect'. please help me
my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.examDemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exam</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>exam</name>
    <description>exam Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.github.gwenn</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>0.1.0</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-community-dialects</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

my SQLiteDialect :

```
package com.examDemo.exam.dialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;

import java.sql.*;

public class SQLiteDialect extends Dialect {
    public SQLiteDialect() {
        registerColumnType(Types.BIT, "integer");
        registerColumnType(Types.TINYINT, "tinyint");
        registerColumnType(Types.SMALLINT, "smallint");
        registerColumnType(Types.INTEGER, "integer");
        registerColumnType(Types.BIGINT, "bigint");
        registerColumnType(Types.FLOAT, "float");
        registerColumnType(Types.REAL, "real");
        registerColumnType(Types.DOUBLE, "double");
        registerColumnType(Types.NUMERIC, "numeric");
        registerColumnType(Types.DECIMAL, "decimal");
        registerColumnType(Types.CHAR, "char");
        registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, "varchar");
        registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, "longvarchar");
        registerColumnType(Types.DATE, "date");
        registerColumnType(Types.TIME, "time");
        registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "timestamp");
        registerColumnType(Types.BINARY, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.VARBINARY, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARBINARY, "blob");
        // registerColumnType(Types.NULL, "null");
        registerColumnType(Types.BLOB, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.CLOB, "clob");
        registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, "integer");

        registerKeyword("concat", new VarArgsSQLFunction(StringType.INSTANCE, "", "||", ""));
        registerKeyword("mod", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StringType.INSTANCE, "?1 % ?2"));
        registerKeyword("substr", new StandardSQLFunction("substr", StringType.INSTANCE));
        registerKeyword("substring", new StandardSQLFunction("substr", StringType.INSTANCE));
    }

    public boolean supportsIdentityColumns() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasDataTypeInIdentityColumn() {
        return false; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
    }

    public String getIdentityColumnString() {
        // return "integer primary key autoincrement";
        return "integer";
    }

    public String getIdentitySelectString() {
        return "select last_insert_rowid()";
    }

    public boolean supportsLimit() {
        return true;
    }

    protected String getLimitString(String query, boolean hasOffset) {
        return new StringBuffer(query.length() + 20).append(query).append(hasOffset ? " limit ? offset ?" : " limit ?")
                .toString();
    }

    public boolean supportsTemporaryTables() {
        return true;
    }

    public String getCreateTemporaryTableString() {
        return "create temporary table if not exists";
    }

    public boolean dropTemporaryTableAfterUse() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean supportsCurrentTimestampSelection() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isCurrentTimestampSelectStringCallable() {
        return false;
    }

    public String getCurrentTimestampSelectString() {
        return "select current_timestamp";
    }

    public boolean supportsUnionAll() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasAlterTable() {
        return false; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
    }

    public boolean dropConstraints() {
        return false;
    }

    public String getAddColumnString() {
        return "add column";
    }

    public String getForUpdateString() {
        return "";
    }

    public boolean supportsOuterJoinForUpdate() {
        return false;
    }

    public String getDropForeignKeyString() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No drop foreign key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
    }

    public String getAddForeignKeyConstraintString(String constraintName, String[] foreignKey, String referencedTable,
                                                   String[] primaryKey, boolean referencesPrimaryKey) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No add foreign key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
    }

    public String getAddPrimaryKeyConstraintString(String constraintName) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No add primary key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
    }

    public boolean supportsIfExistsBeforeTableName() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean supportsCascadeDelete() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I checked many things. and I have watched many videos but no one has encountered this problem unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Use the hibernate community dialects [Hibernate ORM Hibernate Community Dialects for sql dialect git](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-community-dialects/src/main/java/org/hibernate/community/dialect/SQLiteDialect.java).
You don't need to create any dialect for that. just add this dependency

```html
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-community-dialects -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-community-dialects</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```